# How to catch (http) response code with SaxParser.parse

Tags: java, xml-parsing

I'm using SaxParser for parsing an xml I receive from a (OAI)server. This xml can generate another request from me to the server to get another xml and so on.

Some servers can understand these subsequent requests as a denial of service attack and return a "HTTP response code: 503".

How can I catch the response code?

Here is the code I'm using:

```
try
    {
        InputSource is = new InputSource( uri );
        is.setEncoding( "UTF-8" );
        parser.parse( is, handler );
        parsed = true;
    }
    catch ( IOException ioException )
    {
        ...here should happen the response code handling...

        persistError( "Error(IOException) in parsing: " + ioException.getMessage() );
    }
    catch ( SAXException saxException )
    {
        persistError( "Error(SAXException) in parsing: " + saxException.getMessage() );
        // we do not retry to parse if the error is a parsing error
        retry = RETRY_FETCH_URL + 1;
    }
```

Comment: Parsers are the last place you want to "catch" web exceptions, unless the exception gets returned as XML and you want to parse it out. Have you tried catching the exception at the HTTP request level? The logic generally flows along the lines of if HTTP response != 200 --> do something to handle that. Else --> parse the response. You should be able to check the HTTP response code just by look at the returned header from the HTTP request instead of having to parse it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always check the response code before calling the parser.  For example:

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
final int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
if (responseCode < 200 || responseCode > 299) {
    log.info("Response " + responseCode + " opening connection to " + url);
    return;
}
try (Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"))) {
    InputSource is = new InputSource(reader);
    is.setEncoding( "UTF-8" );
    parser.parse(is, handler);
}
```